# How to add a variable name to a path in bash

Tags: bash

I have the variable:

```
sample_name=${E2_ER}
```

and I'd like to add it to a path:

```
files_source=/home/datase/reads/E2_ER/output_files
output_file=${files_source}/merged_${sample_name}
```

Then, I ran another script that merges the files inside the files_source, but writing it like this give me the following file name:

```
merged_.bam
```

How should I change the output_file variable to give me:

```
merged_E2_ER.bam
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, so I need to write: sample_name=E2_ER ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${...}` is for interpolating the contents of variables. If you're not trying to use a variable called `E2_ER`, then the assignment should simply be

```
sample_name=E2_ER
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sample_name=E2_ER
files_source=/home/datase/reads/E2_ER/output_files
output_file=$files_source/merged_$sample_name
```